# Specular highlights with a model imported from Blender?

Tags: three.js

I made in Dice with 2 different colored materials in Blender and exported it with the Blender exporter. In my three.js code, I use JSONLoader to get the mesh and use new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(); as material.

This loads the model just fine with the two different colored materials showing correctly. But my problem is, that I want the dice to have specular highlights on the surface. Is this even possible with exported Blender models?

I managed to get a Sphere with specular highlights when I used THREE.MeshPhongMaterial() as material for the sphere, but the sphere wasn't imported from Blender and as far as I know, I can't apply a Phong Material when I load the Mesh with JSONLoader, or is there a trick? Please remember: I got two differently colored materials on the dice, which I import from Blender in the JSON file. The dice by itself is red, but the dots should be black. So I am not talking about different colors on each side of a cube or so, but two different colors on every side of the cube. Can you help me?

Here's the code snippet:

```
loader.load("models/dice.js", function(geometry){
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial();
    material.specular = 0xffffff;
    material.shininess = 10000000000;
    dice=new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    dice.position.set(0,-400,5);
    dice.scale.set(75, 75, 75);
    dice.overdraw = true;
    dice.name="dice";
    navscene.add(dice);
});
```

If it helps, I am able to create a texture out of the two materials and apply them in Blender, so that the JSONLoader loads the texture instead of the materials, but I wasn't able to achieve a specular highlight either with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mesh geometry has a `materials` array, you can always change the array elements after you load the geometry:

```
geometry.materials[ i ] = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( ... );
```

You then leave the mesh's material as `MeshFaceMaterial`:

```
mesh = new THREE.mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() );
```

The exporter script you are using may set `geometry.materials` to `Lambert` material by default, based on your settings. Have a look at the script source code and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() is just a "pass through" material which is used when the materials are actually part of the geometry.

Answer (score 2):

Thx West, you pointed me into the right direction. The problem was, that Blender's standard material type is Lambert. In Blender, this Lambert material produces the desired specular highlight, but once imported to three, the effect is gone. I don't know if this is a bug, or a desired behaviour.

The solution is to set the material type in Blender to Phong material. This works even after import. My guess is, that THREE.MeshFaceMaterial is an array which contains all the loaded materials, whether they are lambert, phong or whatever. It is even possible to mix those material types. So it appears to me, that THREE.MeshFaceMaterial doesn't seem to be a "stand alone" material type at all. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: This is not the place for conversations. It's for answers. See the comments under my answer below.